# Best implementation of Service Broker when multiple readers needs to read their own message

Tags: service-broker

I have implemented service broker using rusanu.com articles and advices.

Now I need to implement the following scenario :

The service broker will manage Many messages for differents workers and each worker has to receive it's very own message.

What I tried to implement is first keeping One queue for different workers , each worker having it's own Conversation_group_id to send and receive messages.

So to grab the messages I first have to get the conversation_handle of the first message related to my conversation_group

```
SELECT TOP 1 @ConversationHandle = Receiveside.conversation_handle
FROM sys.conversation_endpoints Sendside
JOIN sys.conversation_endpoints Receiveside on Receiveside.conversation_id = Sendside.conversation_id 
WHERE Sendside.far_service = @ReceiveService
      AND Sendside.conversation_group_id = @CurrentConversationGroupID
      AND CONVERT( BIT , Receiveside.is_initiator ) = 0  
      AND Receiveside.far_service = @SendService
      AND Sendside.state <> 'CD'
      AND Receiveside.state <> 'CD'
```

Then I just Receive the message on My queue using the where clause

```
WAITFOR(
   RECEIVE message_type_name ,
                conversation_handle ,
                message_body FROM ddr.DataRelayWebServiceReceiveQueue
   INTO @returnTable
  WHERE CONVERSATION_HANDLE = @ConversationHandle 
) , TIMEOUT 1000;
```

It is functionnal but very poor on the performance side, it takes roughly 25 seconds to dequeue 1500 messages.

I choosed another way which is the creation of as many queues as needed so no collision on the table sys.conversation_endpoints. It takes roughly 16 seconds to dequeue 1500 messages.

I tried to implement Remus rusanu trick which is starting a conversation on the receiving side but without any success.

Any advice on which solution I may choose? I would ideally implement the simple case where two queues could share the same conversation_group_id naturally (without having to search in the table sys.conversation_endpoints), If any of you have already managed to do that I would gladly accept any advice.